# Retrieve row IDs where a property shared by that ID is null for all corresponding rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of items that I'm working with that has two columns: `orderId` and `date`.

If any of an order's items have `date NOT NULL`, the order should be considered "Shipped."  Otherwise, it's "Processing."

I need a query to get all "Shipped" or all "Processing" orders.

Getting shipped is easy:

I can get "Shipped" orders without too much difficulty:

```
SELECT DISTINCT orderId FROM Orders WHERE date IS NOT NULL
```

It doesn't matter if `date IS NULL` for the same `orderId` as long as one of the rows has `date IS NOT NULL`.

---

For getting "Processing," so far I have

```
SELECT orderId FROM Orders GROUP BY orderId HAVING COALESCE(date, NULL) IS NULL
```

but this emits

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Is there any way for me to construct a query that will return all `orderId` where *all* of its corresponding `date`s are `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  Here's one option using `not exists`:

```
select distinct orderId
from Orders o
where not exists  (
  select 1
  from Orders o2 
  where o.orderId = o2.orderId
    and o2.dt is not null)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf305/1)

---

And here's another with conditional aggregation:

```
select orderId
from Orders o
group by orderId
having sum(case when dt is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf305/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX` function in your `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
SELECT orderId FROM Orders GROUP BY orderId HAVING max("DATE") is null
```

If max date for order is null, then all of its dates are nulls indeed.

Comment: Seems like this results in `warning of a null column in an aggregate function`

Comment: Ok, then you can replace max(date) is null by, for an instance, max(nvl(date, '01/01/1970')) = '01/01/1970'. It will guarantee that there will be no nulls inside max function. You can replace first of jan 1970 by something smaller than ever date in your table